SQL query that converts schedule data stored with activity start and end times into counts of minutes in each half hour interval
I have a table that stores data like this:

As you can see, the 10:00-19:00 shift is categorized as 'Open Time', with various other activities sprinkled in throughout the day.
I need to build a query that puts the number of minutes for each activity code into half hour interval buckets like this (The 'Period' column is the start time of the half hour interval.):

How would you write the query using PostgreSQL?
So far I've only built the query that gets the first table and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it very much seems that all your dates end with 00 or 30 minutes. If so, then you can create a table via a subquery, like
JOIN (SELECT generate_series(date '2016-10-16', date '2018-10-17', '30 minute') AS Period) my_dates
ON the_date BETWEEN SHIFT_START_TIME_EST AND SHIFT_START_TIME_END
ORDER BY ...


Offtopic: No need for SELECT in your JOIN, you can join directly to the function generate_series() without using a subquery.
